# How to understand "not even" in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> "I've told the headmaster again and again that you're helping your old friend Black into the castle, Lupin, and here's the proof. **Not even I dreamed you would have the nerve to use this old place as your hideout** --"

I don't quite get what the sentence (in bold) tries to convey. It can be because I don't understand "**not even**". How should we understand the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Not even" is used here as an emphatic negation. The sentence can be rephrased as

> Even I didn't dream you would have the nerve to use this old place as your hideout.

Which is basically saying: "How dare you?"

Comment: No, that's not right. The emphasis is on the *I*, not the dreaming; "Not even I - who already distrusted you - would have thought that you would do this."

Comment: @DanielRoseman I felt the reworded sentence also conveyed that, because I felt in this case action was part of subjectivity (_I wouldn't do this_ says something about me). But yeah, I made the emphasis clearer with a different placement of _even_.